# "Chartkick is not defined" error, using rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm trying to make some simple charts in rails 6, using the chartkick gem. I strictly followed the quickstart on chartkick.com, but I can't get the graphs to load. I keep getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined" in my browser.

I installed the gem.
I ran `yarn add chartkick chart.js`

This is my complete application.js file

```
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("chartkick")
require("chart.js")
```

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb I have the line

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
```

The build itself runs fine, but the js is giving me errors in my browser. Where is this coming from?
I know similar questions have been asked here, but none of them can get me any further.

Comment: What's your Rails version?

Comment: Sorry, edited now

Comment: Strange. this should work... chart.js and chartkick are in your package.json file? did you restart the server?

Comment: They are both in package.json. I restarted the server several times to be sure.

Comment: Hum, the line `<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>` is between `head` tags, after `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was coming from something else entirely. My controller inherited from ActionController::Base instead of ApplicationController, so the javascript packs didn't load from my application.html.erb.

Since I've corrected it, everything works fine now.